# Traceback with storing credentials

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to use the people API to fetch the name of a contact from their phone number in python.
The authentication works fine, I get credentials and I use storage.put(credentials); to save them on disk. The file does get created and there is a bunch of json data in it, looks valid to me. Now I unload my script to test the loading of those credentials using storage.get(), and the first time I'm pretty sure it worked, but since then I get a stacktrace everytime :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/script.py", line 101, in <module>
    credentials = storage.get();
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 422, in get
    return self.locked_get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/file.py", line 66, in locked_get
    credentials = Credentials.new_from_json(content)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 330, in new_from_json
    return kls.from_json(json_data_as_unicode)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 729, in from_json
    data['token_expiry'], EXPIRY_FORMAT)
TypeError: attribute of type 'NoneType' is not callable
```

Any idea what could cause that ? I tried removing the file and re-doing the auth process, it created the file again without any problem, but still that error when trying to read it.
Here is the code :

```
    credentials = gflow.step2_exchange(arg);
    storage = Storage('~/.config/app/creds.dat');
    storage.put(credentials);
```

And when loading :

```
    storage = Storage('~/.config/app/creds.dat');
    credentials = storage.get();
```

EDIT : I'm doing a weechat script, I noticed it works fine the first time I load the script, but every time I unload it / re-load it after that it crashes like that. I assume it's something to do with weechat then, it must be keeping something loaded it shouldn't.